# Selecting siblings of parent of $(this) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I need to update the `id` of all `li` that are siblings of the parent of the `$(this)` element by dynamically counting the present `li` that belong to the same "family" every time one is removed.

Note that there's more than one `ul.customFieldUl` on the page and more than one `li.customFieldLi` in each.

```js
$('.customFieldUl').on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
  var field = $(this).parents('li.customFieldLi');
  if (field.length) {
    field.remove();

    // PROBLEMATIC SELECTOR BELOW:
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(i) {
      var id = i + 1;

      $(this).prop('id', 'field_' + id);
      $(this).find('label#top_title').html('Custom Field #: <b>' + id + '</b> &raquo;');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customFieldUl">
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label id="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label id="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're removing them and trying to work with.... how would you expect them to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `siblings()` of `LI` before removing the `LI` element.

```js
$('.customFieldUl').on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
  var field = $(this).closest('li.customFieldLi');
  //Take reference of siblings
  var siblings = field.siblings();
  
  //Remove element
  field.remove();

  // Now iterate and update properties.
  siblings.each(function(i) {
    var id = i + 1;
    $(this).prop('id', 'field_' + id);
    $(this).find('label#top_title').html('Custom Field #: <b>' + id + '</b> &raquo;');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customFieldUl">
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label id="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label id="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Identifiers in HTML must be unique**, You are using `id="top_title"` multiple times which renders HTML invalid

Note: I totally agree with @Rory's comment, *changing `id` attributes dynamically is not a good idea*

Comment: Thanks for the additional notes, updated `id="top_title"` to class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you're removing the element then trying to select elements based on it. This won't work as the element no longer exists. To fix this, get the related elements first, then perform the removal.

Note that you can simplify the code by using the index parameter provided by `each()`. Also, you've repeated the `top_title` id. You should make that a class. Try this:

```js
$('.customFieldUl').on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $ul = $button.closest('.customFieldUl');
  
  $button.closest('.customFieldLi').remove();
  $ul.find('.customFieldLi').each(function(i) {
    $(this).prop('id', 'field_' + i);
    $(this).find('label.top_title').html('Custom Field #: <b>' + i + '</b> &raquo;');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="customFieldUl">
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
  <li class="customFieldLi">
    <label class="top_title">Additional Field</label>
    <div class="additionalFieldForm"></div>
    <div class="remove-button">Remove</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's also worth noting that changing `id` attributes dynamically is not a good idea. They are meant to be immutable.